# Saving an image to Parse through the REST API, then using it in iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I am developing an application where users are meant to store images on Parse through a web interface. Those images can be then displayed in a native iOS app.

Images are uploaded to Parse through Parse REST API; the URL of the stored image is then saved as a string property of a `PFObject`. This is the javascript code I use to this aim:

```
function postImageToParse(fileName, file, onSuccess, onError) {

    file = file.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpeg|jpg);base64,/, "");

    var binaryImg = atob(file);
    var length = binaryImg.length;
    var ab = new ArrayBuffer(length);
    var ua = new Uint8Array(ab);
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        ua[i] = binaryImg.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    var blob = new Blob([ab],{type:"image/jpeg"});

    var serverUrl = 'https://api.parse.com/1/files/' + basename(fileName);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        beforeSend: function(request) {
            request.setRequestHeader("X-Parse-Application-Id", '...');
            request.setRequestHeader("X-Parse-REST-API-Key", '...');
            request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", file.type);
        },
        url: serverUrl,
        data: blob,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success:onSuccess,
        error:onError
    });
}
```

This is working correctly and I get back a URL of the form:

```
http://files.parse.com/b6a8c6d1-ba52-4d82-bde7-d2f2c9bb6fe4/6279b03f-521a-4481-97ae-553a0396ff98-xyz
```

Now, I have tried to use `PFImageView` on iOS to retrieve/display the image, as explained [here](https://parse.com/questions/saving-an-image-to-parse-through-the-rest-api-then-getting-it-in-ios), but found myself unable to create a `PFFile` to pass as a file property to the `PFImageView` object as required by this snippet:

```
PFImageView *creature = [[PFImageView alloc] init];
creature.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.jpg"]; // placeholder image
creature.file = (PFFile*)file;
[creature loadInBackground];
```

Of course, I can download the image by directly accessing the URL to it that I have stored in my PFObject, but I am wondering if this is correct and if there are better ways to handle this.

So, in the described scenario, how should I get an image stored on Parse for which I have the URL returned by the REST API call used to upload it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up asking the same question on the parse.com forum and got an useful [answer](https://www.parse.com/questions/saving-an-image-to-parse-through-the-rest-api-then-getting-it-in-ios#answer-i-would-use-file-types-and-then-your-ios-code).

It seems that a supported way of managing an image uploaded via the Parse REST API is [associating the image to a previously created object](https://parse.com/docs/rest#files-associating) through another REST call. Doing this would allow to use later `PFFile` on the iOS side.

Answer (score 1):

I looked up the interface of `PFFile` and I didn't find a way of downloading a `PFFile` directly. However, you said that you set the URL of the file as a string property of `PFObject`. Instead, why don't you set that property as a `PFFile`?

```
PFObject *object = ....
PFFile *imageFile = [object objectForKey:@"imageFile"];
creature.file = file;
```

Comment: thanks. I am not uploading the file on iOS/ObjC - I do that from a web page, using the REST API/Javascript SDK, and it has not support for PFFile. That's the point...

Comment: Aha. That's weird. Then I can only think of the answer you said: downloading the image directly from the URL.